# How to remove all duplicated rows in data.table in r

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

Let's say we have

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table(Date = c(201405,201405,201504,201505, 201505,201505), ID = c(500,500,600,700,500, 700), INC = c(20,30,50,75,80,90))
```

return,

```
     Date  ID INC
1: 201405 500  20
2: 201405 500  30
3: 201504 600  50
4: 201505 700  75
5: 201505 500  80
6: 201505 700  90
```

I want to remove all IDs that are in the same Date.  The return should be

```
     Date  ID INC
1: 201504 600  50
2: 201505 500  80
```

Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We group by 'ID', get a logical index with `duplicated` on the 'Date', and negate so that all the unique elements are now TRUE, use `.I` to get the row index, extract the index column 'V1' and use that to subset 'dt'.

```
dt[dt[, .I[!(duplicated(Date)|duplicated(Date, fromLast=TRUE))], ID]$V1]
#      Date  ID INC
#1: 201505 500  80
#2: 201504 600  50
```

Or another option would be to group by 'Date', 'ID' and `if` the nrow is equal to 1 (`.N==1`), we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

```
dt[, if(.N==1) .SD, .(Date, ID)]
#     Date  ID INC
#1: 201504 600  50
#2: 201505 500  80
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can use a data.table/base R combo

```
DT[ave(seq(.N), Date, ID, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1L)]
```

Comment: I had a similar one in `dt[dt[, !(duplicated(ID)|duplicated(ID,fromLast=TRUE)), by=Date]$V1]`

Comment: @thelatemail That also looks right.  I usually go with the `.I`

Comment: I'd consider `DT[ave(seq(.N), Date, ID, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1L)]`. Not very data.table-ish, but it doesn't require using `by` or scanning the vector with `duplicated` twice.

Comment: @Frank - it effectively does use `by` though, in that `ave` calls `lapply` + `split` internally.

Comment: @thelatemail On the basis of nothing whatsoever, I suspect splitting data.frames with `by` has more overhead that splitting a single vector... Oh -- just tested to see if I could make an example and my R session hung on the `ave` after doing the `if (...) .SD` in half a second, so... yep.